# LAMP Stack Setup on Ubuntu: What is 'localhost'?

Tags: mysql, linux, database, wordpress, ubuntu

I'm a total newbie to the world of web development. Trying to setup wordpress.org on Ubuntu.

The tutorial page [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lamp-on-ubuntu-16-04) instructs:

```
sql> GRANT ALL ON wordpress.* TO 'wordpressuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

My computer name is "A"(Static hostname). Should I replace localhost above with A or would local host also work?

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` is the domain name which resolves to `127.0.0.1` which is a special IPv4 address that tells your Link Layer that you are trying to connect to your own computer.

This is useful for testing softwares which work over internet.

---

When using *localhost* as address, latest MySQL releases use *Unix-domain-socket* which doesn't use underlying network protocol but all the communication takes place in OS kernel itself.

---

**Bonus**

- Not only 172.0.0.1 but 127.0.0.1 through 127.255.255.254 all loops-back packets to your machine.

  For IPv6: localhost resolves to ::1.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is set from `/etc/hosts` file. Do not change `localhost` name unless you read & understand what you are doing. This is the  - [manual page for Ubuntu 16.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/hosts.5.html). Open the `/etc/hosts` (or run `cat /etc/hosts`) and you'll see entry like this :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

We can actually change it to something like :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   example.com
```

and reload/restart.

Always run `sudo mysql_secure_installation` command after installation of MySQL. [Here is doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-secure-installation.html). Always follow guides from good tutorial websites. Please read [MySQL Grant Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html). When you are new user, use or [WorkBench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) or [PHPMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net) instead of command line. You should SQL grant just basic privileges to run WordPress. On this command :

```
GRANT ALL ON wordpress.* TO 'wordpressuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

1. wordpress = Use a difficult to guess name like wod678eB
2. wordpressuser = Use a difficult to username like I0od678eB
3. password = Use a difficult to guess name like 78eBwod678eB

Instead of above command this SQL grants just the basic privileges enough for Wordpress to run (SAFER) :

```
CREATE USER 'exampleuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'exampleP@ssw0rd';
CREATE DATABASE exampledatabase;
GRANT SELECT,DELETE,INSERT,UPDATE ON exampledatabase.* TO 'exampleuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```